# Como copiar dados de uma gridview para a outra?

Tags: c#, gridview

como que faço para copiar dados de uma grid para outra adicionado uma linha em branco a cada duas linhas de dados copiadas?

```
    TAB_F_TABELAS_DAL d = new TAB_F_TABELAS_DAL();
    var dados = d.RetornaCronograma(anotual+mesatual,anoanterior+mesanterior);
    CT01_Array.DataSource = dados;
    CT01_Array.DataBind();
```

Comment: Por que você quer fazer? isso? não é melhor resolver com um ItemTemplate? É WindowsForm ou WebForm? Inclua o markup da GridView

Comment: É WebForm, vou testar aqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por favor Rafael Veloso, pode analisar o código abaixo?

```
 private void btnCopiar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.TableName = "MinhaTabela";
        int intConta = 1;

        //Copia as colunas
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridViewOrigem.Columns)
            dt.Columns.Add(col.DataPropertyName, col.ValueType);

        //Copia as linhas
        foreach (DataGridViewRow gridRow in dataGridViewOrigem.Rows)
        {
            if (gridRow.IsNewRow)
                continue;

            //Se for divisível por "3" adiciona uma linha em branco
            if (intConta % 3 == 0)
                dt.Rows.Add();

            intConta++;

            DataRow dtRow = dt.NewRow();

            //Copia cada célula da linha
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < dataGridViewOrigem.Columns.Count; i1++)
                dtRow[i1] = (gridRow.Cells[i1].Value == null ? DBNull.Value : gridRow.Cells[i1].Value);

            dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
        }

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        this.dataGridViewCopia.DataSource = ds.Tables["MinhaTabela"];
    }
```

Comment: eu só não entendi esse dataGridViewSefaz, ele é referente o que?

Comment: OPs... esse datagrid é meu! Você precisa trocar para o nome do seu datagrid de origem. O datagrid de destino fica no "dataGridViewCopia". Vou trocar o nome para "dataGridViewOrigem".